# What is DOCUMENT_ROOT for Atom LiveReload?

Tags: atom-editor

When I start up [Atom LiveReload](https://atom.io/packages/livereload), I get a webserver listening on port 35729, and sure enough, if I go to localhost:35729, I get a blank page.  But where do I put a .html to get served?